# F# and generic type in terfaces

Tags: f#

I have a simple interface that is implemted by couple of classes, so interface looks like:

```
type IResponseBuilder = 
   abstract member FillMessangeFrame<'TResponse> : MessageHeader -> byte array -> Option<'TResponse>
```

As you see Fill message frame returns generic type (as each type it is implemented in returns different type), and type looks like:

```
type ModuleIdentyfication() =
    inherit UdpBaseFrame.BaseFrame()     
    interface IResponseBuilder with

        member this.FillMessangeFrame (header: MessageHeader) (frame: byte array) : Option<'TResponse> = 
            let unknownFrame (msg:string) = msg |> Mediator.UpdMediator.Instance.InvokeUpdDebugLog |> logger.Info
            let messange = ModuleIdentyfiationResponsetMessage()
            match frame <> null, frame.Length >= int header.length with
            | true, true -> 
                let message : Option<ModuleIdentyfiationResponsetMessage> = UdpBaseFrame.Deserialize(frame, 0, messange); 
                message
            | false, _ | _, false -> unknownFrame (sprintf "Unknown or empty header, full frame content:%s" (BitConverter.ToString(frame))); None
```

So as you see when I receive message as a byte array I deserialize it to some type and I want to return this as this type, but it tells me of mismatch of types here

```
message <- problem
```

I tried upcasting it to

```
message :> Option<'TResponse>
```

but no luck, return values mismatch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define the interface this way, you are saying that the `FillMessangeFrame` method is generic and the caller of the method can determine what the generic type parameter will be. However, this is not what you want - the implementation in `ModuleIdentyfication` always returns one specific type of message - that is your `ModuleIdentyfiationResponsetMessage` and the caller of the method does not have control over this!

What you need instead is to define the interface as generic. That way, you can implement the interface for a specific type of message and the class that implements the interface controls what the type will be:

```
type IResponseBuilder<'TResponse> = 
  abstract member FillMessangeFrame : MessageHeader -> byte array -> Option<'TResponse>
```

A dummy implementation that type checks:

```
type ModuleIdentyfication() =
  interface IResponseBuilder<ModuleIdentyfiationResponsetMessage> with
    member this.FillMessangeFrame (header: MessageHeader) (frame: byte array) : Option<_> = 
        Some(ModuleIdentyfiationResponsetMessage())
```